What are the Mormon symbolisms in "Heretic"?
I recently watched Heretic (2024) and read a discussion about Mormon symbolism in the show, which features Mormon missionaries as protagonists. Several symbolic elements appear to reference Mormon religious ceremonies and historical events.
In a discussion about the film on Reddit /r/movies, a viewer has noted that the ways Sisters Barnes (Sophie Thatcher) and Paxton (Chloe East) are attacked appear to reference penalties once associated with breaking oaths of secrecy in the Mormon endowment ceremony. Specifically, Sister Barnes's throat being cut and Sister Paxton being stabbed in the abdomen seem to parallel these historical ceremonial oaths:

At three different stages of the endowment, participants were asked to take an oath of secrecy regarding the ceremony.
Oaths

Throat: The participants first promised, "Should I [reveal any of the secrets], I agree that my throat be cut from ear to ear, and my tongue torn out by its roots"
Heart: "our breasts ... be torn open, our hearts and vitals torn out and given to the birds of the air and the beasts of the field;"
Bowels: "our body ... be cut asunder and all your bowels gush out."


Sister Paxton's survival scene in a sunlit forest also appears to mirror the First Vision, where Joseph Smith, the founder of Mormonism, reportedly encountered God the Father and Jesus Christ.
Are there other Mormon symbolisms in the movie beyond these examples?
